# BDD Android UI testing framework?

Tags: android, cucumber, bdd, robotium, jbehave

I'm looking at using [Frank](http://github.com/moredip/Frank) for UI testing our iOS application(s).  Is there a similar library with support for Android? I'm currently using [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/), but thought it would be nice to be able to specify tests in the same format across both platforms.

Would it be possible to get something like [JBehave](http://jbehave.org/) to run on Android?

Comment: We might end up switching to use WebDriver for everything, based upon http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2011/06/introducing-native-driver.html.

Comment: I recommend you to try this library: https://github.com/mauriciotogneri/green-coffee

You just need to import it and then you will be able to run your tests written in Gherkin.

Comment: I recommend you to try this library: https://github.com/mauriciotogneri/green-coffee

You just need to import it and then you will be able to run your tests written in Gherkin.

Answer (score 7):

As scompt.com said. The project is now officially open sourced and is called Calabash.

I wrote a short blog post about it:
http://blog.lesspainful.com/2012/03/07/Calabash-Android/

Calabash is also available on iOS and with a bit of work and two similar apps you can run the same feature on iOS and Android.

You can read more general stuff about Calabash here:
http://blog.lesspainful.com/2012/03/07/Calabash/

Answer (score 2):

The guys from [lesspainful.com](http://lesspainful.com) have open sourced some of their special sauce on [github](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android). It lets you do cucumber testing on android in the emulator and local devices. Because it's the same code that they're running for their service, you should be  able to test your features on multiple devices if you sign up.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use Cuke4Duke to drive Robotium?  Or use JRuby/Cucumber to drive Robotium?

Comment: Cuke4Duke looks interesting.  I'll give that a shot.  Right now I'm trying to drive Robotium with JBehave.

Comment: If you managed to use Cuke4Duke and Robotium, please, share your solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, robotium is a BDD on dvm not jvm thus no driver exists with jvm frameworks such as jbehave, etc

Answer (score 0):

I've recently started using [www.LessPainful.com](http://www.LessPainful.com) - there are some limitations (you can't write your own steps) and it's quite an early stage company, but so far the testing has at least proved useful, especially with different screen sizes, plus they've automated some good things like orientation (I think they use motors on real phones!).

(for reference on iOS we're using Frank - https://github.com/moredip/frank-  and on WP7 we've written our own - https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework)

Comment: Check out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9278045/111777). LessPainful has [open sourced](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android) some of their cucumber code.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to open-source my work in this area:

https://bitbucket.org/proxama/windows_android_cucumber_runner
https://bitbucket.org/proxama/android_cucumdroid

It allows you to write your own features and steps to exercise the UI automator. This means it runs all on the device.

It's probably not as easy to use as it could be but the Windows gui app is designed to wrap the ANT tasks that make it actually run.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested my app using **MonkeyTalk**. It may help you. https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk